# Error with adding strings onto empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a problem with my program that is supposed to reverse the string by using a function that takes the first word of a string and a function that prints the string without the first word.

```
def first_word(string):
    first_space_pos = string.find(" ")
    word = string[0:first_space_pos]
    print(word)

def last_words(string):
    first_space_pos = string.find(" ")
    words = string[first_space_pos+1:]
    print(words)

def reverse(string):
    words = string.count(" ") +1
    count = 1
    string_reversed = ""
    while count < words:
        string_reversed = first_word(string) + str(" ") + string_reversed
        string = last_words(string)
        count += 1
    print(string_reversed)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

and it's for this line:

```
string_reversed = first_word(string) + str(" ") + string_reversed
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is that really your indentation?

Answer (score 2):

`first_word` doesn't return anything, hence `None` value is produced and can't be used as + operand with string. Probably you want to return `word`.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused **print** and **return**.  **print** dumps a value to the output (your screen), but doesn't change any of the data in memory, and does not do anything further with the value.  **return** sends it back as the function value.

As the complier warning tells me, none of your functions returns any value to the caller.  Thus, you get "None" as the value, and your calling program burfs.  Replace all those terminal **print** statements with **return**'s, and your code works nicely:

```
def first_word(string):
    first_space_pos = string.find(" ")
    word = string[0:first_space_pos]
    return word

def last_words(string):
    first_space_pos = string.find(" ")
    words = string[first_space_pos+1:]
    return words

def reverse(string):
    words = string.count(" ") +1
    count = 1
    string_reversed = ""
    while count < words:
        string_reversed = first_word(string) + str(" ") + string_reversed
        string = last_words(string)
        count += 1
    return string_reversed

print reverse("Now is the time for all good parties to come to the aid of man.")
```

Output:

```
of aid the to come to parties good all for time the is Now
```

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing the functionality of `print` with `return`.

`print` is a python function that will print whatever is in the brackets to whatever may be the `stdout` or another output stream if explicitly specified.

`return` is the statement that sends what you want back as a function value.

IE:

```
>>> def foo():
    print('foo')


>>> def bar():
    return 'bar'

>>> u = foo()
foo
>>> u
>>> type(u)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> u = bar()
>>> u
'bar'
>>> type(u)
<class 'str'>
```

additionally, you can do what you want with the python `str[::-1]`

```
>>> def stringReverse(s):
    print(' '.join(s.split()[::-1]))


>>> stringReverse('Hello this is how to reverse a string')
string a reverse to how is this Hello
```

this is just a suggestion however as you may be trying to do a string reversal in a specific manner. as Prune said, your functions work perfectly fine if you replace `print` with `return`

Answer (score 0):

Both of your methods `first_word()` & `last_words()` does not return anything and therefore a null value is created which cannot be added with a string. Use `return` instead of `print` and it will be good.